# Does anaconda keep a copy of python packages?

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, vtk

I want to uninstall vtk in an Anaconda environment then reinstall it. I have uninstalled the package and removed the environment. To check what is going on I put the comment "If you are reading this that is bad" in `~/anaconda2/envs/testenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vtk/__init__.py`. This is a copy of that code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# --------------------------------------
#If you are reading this that is bad
from .vtkCommonKit import *
from .vtkFiltersKit import *
from .vtkImagingKit import *
from .vtkRenderingKit import *
from .vtkIOKit import *
from .vtkOpenGLKit import *
from .vtkParallelKit import *
from .vtkWrappingKit import *
from .vtkInteractionKit import *
from .vtkViewsKit import *
from .vtkInfovisCore import *
from .vtkChartsCore import *
from .vtkDomainsChemistry import *
from .vtkFiltersFlowPaths import *
from .vtkFiltersHybrid import *
from .vtkImagingHybrid import *
from .vtkInfovisLayout import *
from .vtkGeovisCore import *
from .vtkRenderingGL2PSOpenGL2 import *
from .vtkIOExport import *
from .vtkIOExportOpenGL2 import *
from .vtkIOImport import *
from .vtkIOInfovis import *
from .vtkIOMINC import *
from .vtkIOTecplotTable import *
from .vtkViewsInfovis import *
# --------------------------------------

# useful macro for getting type names
__vtkTypeNameDict = {VTK_VOID:"void",
                     VTK_DOUBLE:"double",
                     VTK_FLOAT:"float",
                     VTK_LONG:"long",
                     VTK_UNSIGNED_LONG:"unsigned long",
                     VTK_INT:"int",
                     VTK_UNSIGNED_INT:"unsigned int",
                     VTK_SHORT:"short",
                     VTK_UNSIGNED_SHORT:"unsigned short",
                     VTK_CHAR:"char",
                     VTK_UNSIGNED_CHAR:"unsigned char",
                     VTK_SIGNED_CHAR:"signed char",
                     VTK_LONG_LONG:"long long",
                     VTK_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG:"unsigned long long",
                     VTK_ID_TYPE:"vtkIdType",
                     VTK_BIT:"bit"}

def vtkImageScalarTypeNameMacro(type):
  return __vtkTypeNameDict[type]

# import convenience decorators
from .util.misc import calldata_type

# import the vtkVariant helpers
from .util.vtkVariant import *
```

I have run:

```
$conda uninstall vtk

$conda env remove --name testenv
```

but if I run:

```
$conda create -n testenv2 python=2.7
$source activate testenv2
$conda install vtk
```

then navigate to the `~/anaconda2/envs/testenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vtk/__init__.py` the comment I made is still there. What is going on and how can I completely purge any backups of this file?

The problem is that it is made for a version of vtk that does not work with python 2.7 that I have done all of my work in. I'm running ubuntu 16.04 in a VM on Windows.

Comment: It might be a symlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this problem, but I'm still not entirely sure what is going on. How I fixed it was the following run in the terminal:

```
$conda env remove --name testenv2
$grep -r vtk ~/anaconda2
```

This returned a massive list but I noticed all of the python and java wrappers were in the ~/anadonda2/pkgs/vtk-6.3.0-py27_1 folder. So I ran:

```
$cd ~/anadonda2/pkgs/
$rm -r vtk-6.3.0-py27_1
$conda create -n newenv python=2.7
$source activate newenv
$conda install vtk
```

Now all of my code runs again in this environment and it seems to be solved.

I left the tarball for vtk 6.3.0 in the pkgs/ folder guessing that it had to extract a new copy of vtk from that folder to rebuild the module. I'm also speculating that the `__init__`.py ended up being written over when I upgraded to the version 8.1.0 of vtk but I'm not sure why there was no package for 8.1.0 in the pkgs/ folder. Is this because it was incompatible with python 2.7? Hopefully this ad hoc solution helps someone at some point at least.